# Pydantic - custom data type that subclasses built-in list

Tags: python, pydantic

The Pydantic example for [Classes with __get_validators__](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#classes-with-__get_validators__) shows how to instruct pydantic to parse/validate a custom data type. The example class inherits from built-in `str`. I'm attempting to do something similar with a class that inherits from built-in `list`, as follows:

```
import typing
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class ListSubclass(list):
    def __init__(
        self,
        the_list: typing.Optional[list] = None,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(the_list or [])

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(
        cls,
    ) -> typing.Generator[typing.Callable[..., typing.Self], None, None]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(
        cls,
        value: typing.Any,
    ) -> typing.Self:
        if type(value) is cls:
            return value
        elif not isinstance(value, list):
            raise TypeError(f'value must be a list or ListSubclass, not {type(value)}')

        return cls(value)


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    test_field: ListSubclass[int] = Field(default_factory=ListSubclass)
```

When I create an instance of `TestModel` with default args and print the type of `test_field`, I get `ListSubclass`, which is great. That's what I expect given the default_factory I supplied.

```
t1 = TestModel()
print(type(t1.test_field))

# outputs
<class '__main__.ListSubclass'>
```

Now, here's where I'm lost. When I create an instance of `TestModel` with explicit args and print the type of `test_field`, I get `list` when I expect it to be `ListSubclass`. I've confirmed that `validate` is being called as expected and the input type is `ListSubclass`.

```
t2 = TestModel(test_field=ListSubclass([1,2,3]))
print(type(t2.test_field))

# outputs
<class 'list'>
```

I assume I'm missing some pydantic-specific configuration, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: To be honest, your code looks mostly right to me. You just forgot the type variable to parameterize the built-in `list` you inherit from (i.e. `T = TypeVar("T")` `class ListSubclass(list[T]): ...`). But that is not relevant to the issue. I can reproduce this and would consider this an error/unexpected behavior. I suggest you open an [issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues) for this.

Comment: Thanks @DaniilFajnberg. I'll open an issue for it (link forthcoming). If I remove the  integer type hint in the model then it works as expected, so it's somehow related to that.

Comment: It appears an issued was already opened for this: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4122) in Pydantic V1 that the maintainers don't intend to support. So, I came up with a workaround. Rather than subclassing `list`, we can wrap it.

```
class ListWrapper(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        the_list: typing.Optional[list[T]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self._wrapped_list = the_list or []

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(
        cls,
    ) -> typing.Generator[typing.Callable[..., typing.Self], None, None]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(
        cls,
        value: typing.Any,
    ) -> typing.Self:
        if type(value) is cls:
            return value
        elif not isinstance(value, list[T]):
            raise TypeError(f'value must be a list or ListWrapper, not {type(value)}')

        return cls(value)

    def __getattr__(
        self,
        name: str,
    ) -> typing.Any:
        return getattr(
            self._wrapped_list,
            name,
        )


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    test_field: ListWrapper[int] = Field(default_factory=ListWrapper)
```

`ListWrapper` inherits from `typing.Generic` to allow parameterization. It also adds a `__getattr__` method, which allows the user to interact with the wrapped list as if it wasn't wrapped. Other methods (`__iter__`, `__str__`, etc.) can be added as needed. We now get the intended result.

```
t1 = TestModel()
print(type(t1.test_field))

t2 = TestModel(test_field=ListWrapper([1,2,3]))
print(type(t2.test_field))
```

produces

```
<class '__main__.ListWrapper'>
<class '__main__.ListWrapper'>
```

A notable downside is that attributes for the wrapped `list` aren't suggested by autocomplete for `ListWrapper` like they would be for `ListSubclass`.